# Unable to hijack Datepicker function again?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

```
>>> var date_time_datepicker = jQuery('#date-time-date').datepicker({inline: true});
>>> date_time_picker.getDate();
#=> undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
date_time_picker.datepicker('getDate');
```